# How to convert a n element from one row of a file to some other row using shell

Tags: linux

example: given file is:

```
Shari ram
Rena gee
```

result required:

```
Shari gee 
Rena ram
```

Comment: How did you arive at the result? Explain the question more precisely

Comment: How did you determine the new mapping. ie How did you determine that 'gee' should be associated to 'Shari'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` to extract columns. Here, I used `tac` to reverse the lines order in the second column (it's not clear what you want). Then, I used process substitution `<(...)` (tested in the `bash` shell) so `paste` works on outputs of the two commands as if given two files. `paste` combines columns from different files.

```
paste <( cut -f1 -d' ' file.txt ) <( cut -f2 -d' ' file.txt | tac )
```

Comment: @jay: What shell are you using?